# Android: Check a method from another class multiple times during runtime

Tags: java, android, android-activity, libgdx

Basically what I am trying to achieve is this; I have an android Activity that executes a game class (built on the libgdx framework) and I need to run a check to see if the game is over by calling a method from within the game class.

Is it possible to run this check multiple times (until the game is over) so that the android Activity can then move on to a different activity when the game is over?

I hope I made myself clear enough,
Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Have you tried it?

Comment: why not to do it the opposite way round, like with events?

Answer (score 2):

Use a BroadcastReceiver and LocalBroadcastManager. Create and register a BroadcastReceiver to catch and handle the game being over. Then, when the game is over call

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(gameOverIntentFilter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use delegate pattern with interfaces.

```
class Game {   
     private OnGameOverListener mListener;
     public void setOnGameOverListener(OnGameOverListener listener) {
          mListener = listener;
     }

    public interface OnGameOverListener{
         public void onGameOver()
    }

    someFunction(..) { 
        listener.onGameOver();// call when game is over
    }


}
```

then implement the OnGameOverListener in the Activity and call finish() in overridden onGameOver method

Comment: answer by toadzky looks better